# Setup git repo post-receive on Windows

Tags: windows, git, git-post-receive

I would like to setup git deployment on my Windows server, but I'm having some trouble changing director from the git post-receive event. I get a "No such file or directory" error.

I have the following setup:

1. a git repository on a Windows share //share/git/repo/
2. a post-receive configure as following:

   #!/bin/sh

   echo "Building the Arla Solution"

   cd /c/Builds

   unset GIT_DIR

   git pull origin master

   echo "Doing some post build actions..."

When I do a commit/push to the repository if fails on the line: `cd C:/Builds`.

I've setup something similar on a Linux server (VPS) without any problems. I think the problem is how I've formatted the change directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`git`'s bash (AFAIK) is unfamiliar with `C:`,
Try replacing the relevant line to `/c/Builds`
Keep in mind `bash` is case sensitive unlike `Windows`

Comment: I've tried this also, and get a similar error:
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 5: cd: /c/Builds: No such file or directory

Comment: Do you get the first line to execute (i.e. see "Building the Arla Solution")? if so add a 2nd line "echo \`ls /\`; echo \`ls /c/\`" to see the folders you have (or do so in the git bash)